# Mozart-Oz difference between String and Atom

Tags: types, oz, mozart

Could anyone provide a concise explanation of the difference between String and Atom types in the Oz programming language? I found the documentation lacking.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `sting` is a list containing characters, while `atom` is an empty record (record with a label but without components).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the type hierarchy shown in the CTM book.
[image: The type hierarchy]

According to this, an atom is a kind of record. Unlike other kinds of records, atoms do not have an internal structure. A string is just syntactic sugar for a list, and as such, will have all the other properties of a list, such as getting represented in terms of `Head|Tail`, terminated by `nil`, etc.

You can play around with these two examples to further your understanding:

```
{Browse 'hello'==hello} % prints true, neither is a string

{Browse "hello"==[104 101 108 108 111]} % prints true, equivalent representations of the same string

{Browse 'hello'=="hello"} % prints false
```